# How to access strings from a public class/function

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have a rather simple problem i guess.

I want to create a function which counts up to 5 and creates a random value for each of the 5 strings, like "`string p1 = rnd.Next(1, 15)`" < this happens in a function, like this:

```
    class dice
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();


        public void rollit()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
        }
        public static void diceTeam()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    //Random rnd = new Random();
                    string p1 = rnd.Next().ToString();
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    //Random rnd = new Random();
                    rnd.Next();
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    //Random rnd = new Random();
                    rnd.Next();
                }
                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    //Random rnd = new Random();
                    rnd.Next();
                }
                else if (i == 5)
                {
                    //Random rnd = new Random();
                    rnd.Next();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now after creating the function i want to display the random value in a windows forms application with a label. I want to do it by clicking a button and get all 5 values displayed at once, like this:

```
    private void BtnDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (teamBox.Checked == true)
        {
            player1.Text = dice.diceTeam();
        }
    }
```

but it's giving me a red curly underline at dice.diceTeam(), this is probably because i need to specify the p1 string, but how do i do that?

Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: `diceTeam` has a return type of `void` (so it doesn't return anything) - you would need to change that to `string` and have your method return the string

Comment: okay, now i get the error that not all codepaths are returning a value after changing void to string. and i don't know how to make p1 publicly available . because i need to declare that player1.Text should equal p1 from dice.diceTeam().

Comment: You need to return something in the diceTeam method you properly only change void into string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your method has the return type void, while the textBox is expecting a string. However, it's not clear what exactly you *want* to return - I'll just assume that you want to return a specific random number. Then you could use this:

```
public static string diceTeam()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    string res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            res += rnd.Next().ToString();
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            res += rnd.Next().ToString();
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            res += rnd.Next().ToString();
        }
        else if (i == 4)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            res += rnd.Next().ToString();
        }
        else if (i == 5)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            res += rnd.Next().ToString();
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

However, I don't understand what your code is supposed to do - I mean, why do you check what value i has, if you do the same everytime? You could simplify this code like that:

```
public static string diceTeam() => Enumerable.Repeat(new Random(), 5)
    .Select(rnd => rnd.Next().ToString())
    .Aggregate((s0, s1) => $"{s0},{s1}");
```

I'm not sure wether you wanted to achieve that, otherwise you'll have to clarify your intentions.

---

**EDIT**:

After I saw your comment, I got even more confused. You only want p1 be available? Then you could do this:

```
public static string diceTeam() => new Random().Next().ToString();
```

But if you really want your p1 to be available, you'd have to use it as a reference (I'd use `out` here):

```
public static void diceTeam(out string p1)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    p1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            p1 = rnd.Next().ToString();
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
        else if (i == 4)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
        else if (i == 5)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
    }
}
```

Which could again be simplified to

```
public static void diceTeam(out string p1) => p1 = new Random().Next().ToString();
```

You'd have to call the method like that:

```
private void BtnDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (teamBox.Checked == true)
    {
        dice.diceTeam(out string result);
        player1.Text = result;
    }
}
```

For more information about the `out` keyword, take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx.

---

**EDIT:**

If you actually want `p1` to be available everywhere, you'll have to use a global static variable:

```
public static string p1;
public static void diceTeam()
{
    p1 = "";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            p1 = rnd.Next().ToString();
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
        else if (i == 4)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
        else if (i == 5)
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next();
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like that:

```
private void BtnDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (teamBox.Checked == true)
    {
        dice.diceTeam();
        player1.Text = dice.p1;
    }
}
```

---

And

```
dice.diceTeam (out string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
```

wouldn't work - you'd have to use:

```
dice.diceTeam (out string p1, out string p2, out string p3, out string p4, out string p5);
```

.

Comment: what does the var res do? because i have 5 labels called player1 to player5, and need to give them all a random number from 1 to 15, the numbers later refer to another method which contains the playerId

Comment: `var` stands for variable. It can be replaced with `string` in this context - I'll update my answer.

Comment: so i can use `public static void diceTeam(out string p1)` to make the string p1 available in all areas? can i also do it like `public static void diceTeam(out string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)` to get all strings from p1 to p5?

Comment: Actually, now again it's a local variable. I'll update my answer again.

Comment: sorry :/ i'm just a hobbyist programmer :)

Comment: `            if (teamBox.Checked == true)
            {
                dice.diceTeam()
                player1.Text = dice.p1;
            }` this now tells me that player1 (without .Text) needs a `;` SOLVED! thanks anyways

Comment: @Richard then mark the answer as an answer and the topic's closed :)